# Custom Control not updating on partial postback

Tags: vb.net, postback, ascx

I have a custom control of which I have included 2 in an aspx page.  I want to be able to select a value from the first one and this will then populate the second one by partial postback.  I have spent quite a bit of time googling for an answer on how to do this, but I cannot get the 2nd control in my page to render with new values following partial postback.

CustomDDL.ascx.vb

```
Imports System.Data
Public Class CustomDDL
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    'Input Variables
    Private _OptionText As List(Of String)
    Public Property OptionText() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return ViewState("OptionText")
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            ViewState("OptionText") = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _OptionValue As List(Of String)
    Public Property OptionValue() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return ViewState("OptionValue")
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            ViewState("OptionValue") = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property UpdateMode() As UpdatePanelUpdateMode
        Get
            Return Me.DDLUpdatePanel.UpdateMode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As UpdatePanelUpdateMode)
            Me.DDLUpdatePanel.UpdateMode = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub Update()
        Me.DDLUpdatePanel.Update()
    End Sub
    Public Property Width As Integer = 200
    Public Property TextboxHeight As Integer = 30
    Public Property OptionHeight As Integer = 30
    Public Property OptionsToView As Integer = 10
    Public Property TextColor As String = "black"
    Public Property BackgroundColor1 As String = "white"
    Public Property BackgroundColor2 As String = "white"
    Public Property ImageUrl As String = ""
    Public Property TextBoxFontSize As Integer = 12
    Public Property OptionFontSize As Integer = 12
    'Output Variables
    Public Property SelectedText() As String
        Get
            Return TB_Text.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            TB_Text.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property SelectedValue() As String
        Get
            Return TB_Value.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            TB_Value.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Event SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Sub btnButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Clicker.Click
        RaiseEvent SelectedIndexChanged(Me, e)
        bindRepeater()
        TB_Text.Text = SelectedText
        TB_Value.Text = SelectedValue
        Selected.InnerHtml = SelectedText
    End Sub

    Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        Dim stophere As String = ""
    End Sub



    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Selected.Style.Add("font-size", CStr(TextBoxFontSize) + "px")
        DDLOuter.Style.Add("width", CStr(Width) + "px")
        outer.Style.Add("width", CStr(Width) + "px")
        outer.Style.Add("line-height", CStr(TextboxHeight) + "px")
        outer.Style.Add("height", CStr(TextboxHeight) + "px")
        outer.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer")
        divInnerTB.Style.Add("line-height", CStr(TextboxHeight) + "px")
        divInnerTB.Style.Add("height", CStr(TextboxHeight) + "px")
        divInnerTB.Style.Add("width", CStr(Width - 40) + "px")
        divDropimage.Style.Add("line-height", CStr(TextboxHeight) + "px")
        divDropimage.Style.Add("height", CStr(TextboxHeight) + "px")
        Selected.Style.Add("width", CStr(Width - 20) + "px")
        spacer.Style.Add("height", "3px")
        spacer.Style.Add("width", CStr(Width) + "px")
        spacer.Style.Add("color", TextColor)
        spacer.Style.Add("background-color", BackgroundColor1)
        outer.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return toggleDDL('" + Me.ID + "_DDLOuter')")
        If ImageUrl = "" Then
            DropImage.Visible = False
        Else
            DropImage.ImageUrl = ImageUrl
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(OptionText) Then
            Dim amountOptions As Integer = OptionText.Count
            Dim scrollY As String = ""
            Dim scrollheight As Integer = 0
            Dim scrollnumber As Integer = 0
            If amountOptions < OptionsToView Then
                scrollY = "hidden"
                scrollnumber = amountOptions
            Else
                scrollY = "scroll"
                scrollnumber = OptionsToView
            End If
            scrollheight = scrollnumber * OptionHeight
            DDLOuter.Style.Add("overflow-y", scrollY)

            DDLOuter.Style.Add("max-height", CStr(scrollheight) + "px")
            bindRepeater()

        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub bindRepeater()
        Dim table As New DataTable
        table.Columns.Add("Item", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Value", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Style", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("alternatingStyle", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("transfer", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        For i = 0 To OptionText.Count - 1
            If Not IsNothing(OptionValue) Then
                If Not IsNothing(OptionValue(i)) Then
                    table.Rows.Add(OptionText(i), OptionValue(i), "font-size:" + CStr(OptionFontSize) + "px;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;height:" + CStr(OptionHeight - 10) + "px;width:" + CStr(Width) + "px; color:" + TextColor + ";background-color:" + BackgroundColor1 + ";", "font-size:" + CStr(OptionFontSize) + "px;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;height:" + CStr(OptionHeight - 10) + "px;width:" + CStr(Width) + "px; color:" + TextColor + ";background-color:" + BackgroundColor2 + ";", "transferItem(this.id,""" + Me.ID + "_TB_Text"",""" + Me.ID + "_Selected"",""" + Me.ID + "_Clicker"",""" + OptionValue(i) + """,""" + Me.ID + "_TB_Value"");")
                Else
                    table.Rows.Add(OptionText(i), "", "font-size:" + CStr(OptionFontSize) + "px;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;height:" + CStr(OptionHeight - 10) + "px;width:" + CStr(Width) + "px; color:" + TextColor + ";background-color:" + BackgroundColor1 + ";", "font-size:" + CStr(OptionFontSize) + "px;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;height:" + CStr(OptionHeight - 10) + "px;width:" + CStr(Width) + "px; color:" + TextColor + ";background-color:" + BackgroundColor2 + ";", "transferItem(this.id,""" + Me.ID + "_TB_Text"",""" + Me.ID + "_Selected"",""" + Me.ID + "_Clicker"","" "",""" + Me.ID + "_TB_Value"");")
                End If
            Else
                table.Rows.Add(OptionText(i), "", "font-size:" + CStr(OptionFontSize) + "px;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;height:" + CStr(OptionHeight - 10) + "px;width:" + CStr(Width) + "px; color:" + TextColor + ";background-color:" + BackgroundColor1 + ";", "font-size:" + CStr(OptionFontSize) + "px;cursor:pointer;padding:5px;height:" + CStr(OptionHeight - 10) + "px;width:" + CStr(Width) + "px; color:" + TextColor + ";background-color:" + BackgroundColor2 + ";", "transferItem(this.id,""" + Me.ID + "_TB_Text"",""" + Me.ID + "_Selected"",""" + Me.ID + "_Clicker"","" "",""" + Me.ID + "_TB_Value"");")
            End If
        Next
        repeater.DataSource = table
        repeater.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Page_Unload(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
        Dim stophere As String = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

CustomDDL.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" ClassName="CustomControl.CustomDDL" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="CustomDDL.ascx.vb" Inherits="CustomControlLibrary.CustomDDL" %>
<style type="text/css">
    .DDLOuter
    {
        transition: height 1s;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
    }

    .Open
    {
        transition-property: height;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
        transition-duration: 0s;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var DDLID;
    if (typeof toggleDDL != 'function') {
        function toggleDDL(id) {
            DDLID = id;
            clearClass(id, resetClass);

        }
    }
    if (typeof clearClass != 'function') {
        function clearClass(id, callBack) {
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("Open");
            for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                if (divs.item(i).id != id) {
                    divs.item(i).style.height = "0%";

                }
            }
            return callBack(id, toggleClass);
        }
    }
    if (typeof resetClass != 'function') {
        function resetClass(id, callBack) {
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("Open");
            for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                if (divs.item(i).id != id) {
                    var DivClass2 = divs.item(i).className;
                    divs.item(i).className = DivClass2.replace("Open", "")
                }
            }
            return callBack(id);
        }
    }
    if (typeof toggleClass != 'function') {
        function toggleClass(id) {
            if (document.getElementById(id).style.height == "100%") {
                document.getElementById(id).style.height = "0%";
                var DivClass = document.getElementById(id).className;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById(id).className = DivClass.replace("Open", "")
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.height = "100%";
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.getElementById(id).className += " Open"

                }, 1000);

            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (typeof transferItem != 'function') {
        function transferItem(id, target, display, button, OptVal, OptTarget) {
            var value = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById(target).value = value;
            document.getElementById(OptTarget).value = OptVal;
            document.getElementById(display).innerHTML = value;
            document.getElementById(button).click();
            toggleDDL(DDLID);
        }
    }


</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DDLUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <div id="outer" runat="server" style='border-radius: 3px; color: #404040; font-size: 13px;
                background-color: White; cursor: pointer;'>
                <div runat="server" id="divInnerTB" style="float: left;">
                    <div runat="server" style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: 16px;" id="Selected">
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divDropimage" runat="server" style="float: right; width: 30px; text-align: center;
                    margin-right: 10px;">
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="DropImage" Style="max-height: 30px; max-width: 30px;
                        vertical-align: middle;" />
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TB_Text" Style="display: none;"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TB_Value" Style="display: none;"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div id="DDLOuter" class="DDLOuter" runat="server" style="height: 0%; position: absolute;
                overflow-x: hidden; margin-top: -3px">
                <div id="DDLInner">
                    <div runat="server" id="spacer" style="height: 3px">
                        &nbsp;</div>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Clicker" Style="display: none;" />
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.style")%>'>
                                <asp:Label onClick='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.transfer")%>' runat="server"
                                    ID="Item" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Item")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <div style='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.alternatingstyle")%>'>
                                <asp:Label onClick='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.transfer")%>' runat="server"
                                    ID="Item" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Item")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

WebForm1.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: Gray">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="True"
        EnableScriptLocalization="True" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="update1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="first" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:CustomDDL runat="server" ID="first" />
                <asp:CustomDDL runat="server" ID="second" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Webform1.aspx.vb

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim a As New List(Of String)
            Dim b As New List(Of String)

            a.Add("First")
            b.Add("1")
            a.Add("First")
            b.Add("1")
            a.Add("First")
            a.Add("First")

            b.Add("1")
            b.Add("1")
            first.OptionValue = b
            first.OptionText = a
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub testthis_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles first.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim a As New List(Of String)
        Dim b As New List(Of String)

        a.Add("second")
        b.Add("1")
        a.Add("second")
        b.Add("1")
        a.Add("second")
        a.Add("second")

        b.Add("1")
        b.Add("1")
        second.OptionValue = b
        second.OptionText = b

    End Sub
End Class
```

Anyone any thoughts on where I'm going wrong with this??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding  the `AutoPostBack="true"` in your customDDL in your WebForm1.aspx ?

```
<asp:CustomDDL runat="server" ID="first" AutoPostBack="true" />
```